# The latest updates .. 5/26/17

Tags: updates

I installed the latest updates this morning and now my system is not booting correctly.  I think it's because I have Nvidia drivers / CUDA installed.  How do I repair / return to previous release?  I am able to start system by selecting the previous release in grub.

Thanks,
Mike